# Javascript Remove specific only needed n-th elements of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

For example i have an array

> var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "App", "Man"];

The code

```
fruits.splice(2, 2);
```

Return me output

> Banana,Orange,App,Man

But how to return only 1,3,4 elements from array without looping?

So i will get

> Orange,Mango,App

I imaging must be something like that

```
fruits.splice( fruits.indexOf(Orange,Mango,App), 1 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter` to filter out certain items:

```
fruits = fruits.filter(function (e, i) {
    return i === 1 || i === 3 || i === 4;
});
```

Or if you want to keep certain items based on their identity (which seems to be what you're trying to do at the end of your question):

```
fruits = fruits.filter(function (e) {
    return e === "Orange" || e === "Mango" || e === "App";
});
```

Comment: It should be noted that the `filter` function is still looping.

Comment: @AaditMShah Yes, I didn't notice the "without looping" part of the question, but adding or removing items in an array will almost always require a loop of some kind, and the above is much cleaner and less error-prone than an explicit loop.

Answer (score 1):

The same as [JLRishe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1945651/jlrishe)'s answer but with the addition that you can pass in a list of those elements that you want to keep:

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "App", "Man"];
var list = 'Orange, Mango, App';

alert(strip(fruits, list)); // ["Orange", "Mango", "App"]

function strip(arr, list) {
    list = list.split(', ');
    return arr.filter(function (el) {
      return list.indexOf(el) > -1;
    });
}
```

Comment: Good but @JLRishe is shorter, overwise +1

Comment: Thanks. Mine allows for a little more flexibility tho :)

Comment: Flexibility if search by names i need by elements position

Answer (score 0):

You may combine `slice` and `splice` methods:

```
 var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "App", "Man"]; 
 fruits.splice(2,1);
 var x = fruits.slice(1,4); 
 x;
```

Explanation:

- `splice` deletes 1 element starting at index 2 ( ie. "Apple" ).
- `slice` extracts 3 elements starting at index 1 ( ie. "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "App"; remember that at this time, the array no longer contains "Apple").

Variation (non-destructive):

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "App", "Man"]; 
var x = fruits.slice(1,2).concat(fruits.slice(3,5));
x;
```

Comment: downvoter, i'm very happy to learn about the deficiencies of the solution presented, which is much easier receiving a comment beyond the downvote itself.

Comment: i did not mean to imply you would.